# Rails, Outputing a List of Users & Specifying if they are permissioned or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's what I have today:
I output a list of @users

What I need to do is output a list of users and say if they are assigned to the current project.

I could loop through each user and check in the database, but that would be a lot of data base hits, an additional 10 hits for displaying 10 users.

My question to you, is there a smart, more efficient, rails way to do this? Ideas:
Perhaps I load a list of all of a project's current users, and check against that array when outputting through the user's loop? Or maybe some other method?

Interested in hear your suggestions and if you don't mind a small code snippet to get me started.

Thank you!

**UPDATE - adding models**

```
User model
belongs_to :instance
has_many :permissions
has_many :projects, :through => :permissions

Permissions Model:
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :project 
belongs_to :role

Project Model:
has_many :permissions
has_many :users, :through => :permissions
```

The query I'm using currently is:

```
@users = find(:all, :joins => :instance, :select => 'users.*, instances.domain', :conditions => ['fname LIKE ? or lname LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```

What I want to know is, for the user being displayed. Are they currently a member of the project_id in the URL? Or if not, show an ADD Member button.

Answer (score 1):

[Use :include](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)  (Just check this **4.1.2.7 :include** )

```
 User.all( :include =>:projects )
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure what (4.1.2.7 :include) is? Also, the thing is I want to display a list of users and say if they are in the project or note (based on a permissions table)... I'm not trying to show just those in the project. But a long list of user's and if they are or not a team member.

Comment: Just check the link i provided and article 4.1.2.7 :include. Can u provide some code of your models.

Comment: Still trying to grasp this. Very interesting, hasn't clicked yet. The docs I read for "4.1.2.7 :include" talk about using include in the model not the query. Which are you proposing? Code of models added above. Thoughts?

Comment: I tried something like this when I output every user. But this hits the database everytime. It also errord. thoughts? "<%= Permission.where(:user_id=> searchresult.id ).where(:project_id=> @project.id).first %>"